# OutputCache not working for a single News page in Composite C1 CMS

Tags: asp.net, outputcache, c1-cms

I've just installed the Composite.News package and trying to make it work together with OutputCache.
The News page itself is being serviced by OutputCache, but the single NewsItem with url like News/2013/02/22/MyNewsItem doesn't wish to be cached!

Is there any way to enable OutputCache for a NewsItems (and for any urls registered with RegisterPathInfoUsage in general)?
Thanks!